# Pass a variable that is not set in a PHP function

Tags: php, isset

I get a lot of array from some API and I need to check weither some variable exist or not.

I have a lot of block that look like that :

```
if (isset($var))
    $varToSet = $var;
else
    $varToSet = '';
```

So I've decided to make a function for that. I came with that:

```
function setVar($var)
{
    if (isset($var))
        return $var;
    return '';
}
```

But as I would expected I got the error `Undefined variable`, I figured out I needed to passe the argument by reference so I would get the following prototype :

```
function setVar(&$var);
```

And It was working perfectly until now, here's an example of my problem :

```
// works fine
$var = "test";
$varToSet = setVar($var);

// works fine
$var = "test";
$varToSet = setVar($doesNotExist);

// works fine
$var = "test";
$varToSet = setVar($doesNotExist['index']);

// doesn't work
$var = "test";
$varToSet = setVar($var['index']);
```

In the last example I get `Illegal string offset 'index` and `Only variables can be passed by reference` PHP errors.
I know why I got those errors, I just can't figure out how overcome this problem.

Comment: @meagar those variable names are not mine

Comment: Seems like array values will always be a problem and PHP won't let do that. Why do you need to turn it into a function ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet I need a function because I check something like 100 values, so it's clearer and more readable.

Comment: But impossible. What about `$varToSet = (isset($var['index'])) ? $var['index'] : '';` ? Would it be convenient ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet This is passing by value, because you are passing empty string. It won't work

Comment: @ClémentMalet Yeah I thought about it, but still, it's not that clear. That's what I'll do if I can't figure out something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives you the answer. Your variable is a string. But you are trying to access an array element by using brackets [ ].

And the second is caused by invalid refference.

This is passing by reference:

```
$variable = 'test'; 
myFunction($variable);
```

and this is passing by value:

```
myFunction('test');
```

That's a big difference!

You can't call string as array

```
$varToSet = setVar($var['index']);
```

You can change the line to:

```
echo $var['index'];
```

and you will still have the same error/warning.
If you want to validate if array variable is set use

```
isset($var['index'])
```

but it returns value, not a refference

Comment: Thanks but I said I knew why it wouldn't work, I need a solution. Also here's a link for `reference`, it might help you http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @Łukasz `$variable = 'test'; myFunction($variable);` is **not** passing by reference.

Comment: If in my function declaration I have got myFunction(&variable). Yes, it's passing by reference.

Comment: @Łukasz Then you were quite unclear. Nevermind, the problem here is not related to the pass-by-reference method.

Comment: There are a lot of problem with that code. I wrote also about calling array's element on string. Did you see that?

Answer (score 0):

i mainly use property_exists to check if a value exist on a  json object.

```
function getFromJson($json,$value) 
{
    if (property_exists(json, $value)) {
       return $json->$value;
     }
   return null;
}

function get($var,$value = null) 
{
    if (is_null($value)) {
       return $var;
    }
    if (is_object($var) && property_exists($var, $value)) {
       return $json->$value;
     }
    if (is_array($var)) {
       return $var[$value];
    }
   return $var;
}
```

Comment: My question might have confuse you, but it has nothing to do with Json. I edited it. Sorry.

Comment: $var = "test";
$varToSet = setVar($var['index']); - $var is a string and you cant do $var['anything'] on that string

Comment: updated above example for a more common function to handle json, array, values